# Cast a record returned by DataReader to EF entity

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I have a project that implements my domain based on conventional EF Code First pocos. All conventional CRUD functionality is in place. Now, I'm trying to interface with a legacy database that is not backed by EF. These 2 dbs  (EF-backed and the older legacy) have similar but not identical schemas.

There is a way to hit my legacy db with ado.net and cast the output to a type that's defined by EF (without having to hand-map each property). I know, because a couple years ago, i implemented such a beast. But I don't have access to that code anymore and it's a really tough search expression with which to feed the Google.

Comment: Something similar to ObjectContext.Translate ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn219937(v=vs.113).aspx 

http://dotnetfriendly.blogspot.fr/2010/07/objectcontext-translate-in-entity.html

Comment: I'm not recognizing it as such but the prior code is not accessible to me and  that'd be on me. I wonder if a lambda wrapper around the result set?